# How To Display SQL Database In Table Format

Tags: c#, mysql, format, odbc

I'm working on retrieving data from a cloud server that uses MySQL for a Database. I can retrieve the data *but* I want to format the **command prompt** to show 5 columns with the given number of records. Here's an example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    ITEM         |    QUANT     |    SIZE    |    COLOR    |   PRICE   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 |              |            |             |           |
|                 |              |            |             |           |
|                 |              |            |             |           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the code I'm currently using & thanks to anyone for helping out:

```
     //Loop through all data results
 foreach (DataRow dataRow in theTable.Rows)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("[ITEM]");
 Console.WriteLine          ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
 using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString))
 {
 con.Open();

 using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT invent_desc, qoh int, itemsize,      color, curr_price FROM item,inventory", con))
 {
 using (OdbcDataReader oReader = com.ExecuteReader())
 {
 while (oReader.Read())

 Console.WriteLine(oReader[0] + "       " + oReader[1] + " "  + oReader[2] + "      "      + ((decimal)oReader[3]) + "       " + oReader[4]);

                        }//end using reader
                    }//end usin
```

**NEW EDIT** The snipplet below works but unfortunately it does't organize the tables really good. Could someone still assit?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

```
  using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString)) {
    con.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM item,inventory", con)) {
         using (OdbcDataReader oReader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (oReader.Read()) 
               Console.WriteLine(oReader[0] + " " + oReader[1] + " " + oReader[2] + " " + oReader[3]+ " " + oReader[4]);

         }//end using reader
     }//end usin
```

I would suggest you to do something like this

```
 Console.WriteLine(oReader[0] + " " + oReader[1] + " " + oReader[2] + " " + oReader[3]+ " " + oReader[4]);
```

Above will give you the o/p

Comment: When I add " using (ODBCClass o = new ODBCClass())" I get a namespace error

Comment: I hate to be a newb saying this - but I now have **"oReader"** making an error saying "does not exist in content".

Comment: Can you rename the OdbcDataReader reader to OdbcDataReader oReader  ... This is a silly mistake :) Hope this will work

Comment: The problem is here "OdbcDataReader oReader"    check the variable name and update change it

Comment: Thank you *But* the only problem now is that it doesn't populate the tables   in a stright line - its kinda all over the place. Would their be a way to "Filter" what values I wanted to be shown?

Comment: Yes, You can even specify the selected field name, or the array index like that